# jQuery + qTip2 - Select current hover element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hover, qtip2

I am using qTip2 to display tooltip for the table rows:

```
   @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr id="@(item.ShopListID)">
                <td id="name@(item.ShopListFoodID)" class="shoptablename">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td id="amnt@(item.ShopListFoodID)" class="shoptableamount">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Amount)
                </td>
            </tr>

        }
```

I want to have the tooltip for each "Amount" field, so I initiate the tooltip like this:

```
    // Use ajax to add tooltip for food with stock amount
    $('.shoptableamount').qtip($.extend({}, myStyle, {
        content: {
            text: 'Loading...', // The text to use whilst the AJAX request is loading
            ajax: {
                url: '/Shop/GetFoodAmount', 
                type: 'GET',
                data: { id: $('.shoptableamount').attr('id') } 
            }
        }
    }));
```

However, since i select using the class, I only get the id of the first tr, and no matter I have my mouse over on which row, I still get the some tooltip content as the first row. I tried to use $(this) to select the id, but I did not work.

I need a selector which I can select the current hover element...

Hope can get some help here... any feedback is appreciated...

Thanks....

Comment: hi, $(this).attr('id') returns 1,2,3... for the first, second and third row..

Comment: hmm then try using $(this, '.shoptableamount') to get the tooltip

Comment: hi, thanks, but it dint work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried getting tooptip on hover, here is my code you have to provide tooltip for all the different td's

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Qtip on Hover</title>
<script src="jquery.1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js"></script>

    <style>
    .className {
        color: red;
    }

    .classValue {
        color: green;
    }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.classValue').each(function() {
                $(this).qtip({
                    content : $(this).text() + "_" + $(this).attr('id')
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>

                <th>Value</th>

            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="name1" class="className">test1</td>
                    <td id="value1" class="classValue">test1Val</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="name2" class="className">test2</td>
                    <td id="value2" class="classValue">test2Val</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td id="name3" class="className">test3</td>
                    <td id="value3" class="classValue">test3Val</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. I get a similar solution from qTip support, using the .each too loop through each td :) Thanks